# Does Exchange enable MDM automatically on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-device-management, enterprise

My employer recommended that I sign into our corporate email (Google hosted) via Exchange in the Mail app. I found out later that by doing so, I automatically enabled MDM or allowed them to set policies on my phone. (We learned this when another employee lost their iPhone and our IT department helped to lock it with their console.)

I did not install any profile or certificate and those tabs are empty/missing in my settings. Nothing stood out in the signin flow either (I certainly wouldn't have pressed "Allow your employer to access X" buttons.)

Does using Exchange automatically enroll you in an MDM policy? Is there a way to opt out or continue using Exchange w/o giving up my rights?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it could be done automatically when you sign into an exchange account. If your device is under MDM policy you will find a configuration profile in the Settings.

**How to delete a configuration profile on iOS**

1. Open Settings on your iOS device.
2. Go to the section General → Profiles & Device Management, or Settings → General → Profiles.
3. Tap on a configuration profile you would like to remove from your iOS device.

[image: How to delete configuration profile]

4. Tap Delete Profile at the bottom of the configuration profile screen.
5. Enter your passcode, if required.

[image: How to delete configuration profile]

6. Confirm that you would like to remove the selected configuration profile from your device by tapping Delete. When you delete a profile, all of the settings and accounts associated with the profile are also removed.
7. It is always a good idea to restart your iOS device after removing a profile.

Comment: I don't have this subsection in General and no profile is installed. Yet IT says that my device is enrolled in MDM... Are they mistaken?